# POST a file and GET it's modificated version

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting trouble with a little project. Let's start with my functional goal :

> I've got a Word document & a JSON, I merge the data to get one single Word document.

So, I created a basic Webapp which contains a form with a file (the word document) and a json text-editor. Once both filled, I click on generate, and i'd like to instantly download the file generated.

I made a route called */upload*, with a POST method which handles the file.

But, I'm lost on how to lazily do this. (POST with UUID, then on response GET file from UUID ? That's not the cleanest way to do this.. Or maybe i'm wrong)

I'd like to know how I can POST my file and download it's new version with a single action.

I made this kind of stuff, but i'm pretty sure I can do way better  :

```
const JSZip = require('jszip');
const Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const formidable = require('formidable');

/*
* POST
* /upload
*/

exports.postFileUpload = (req, res) => {

  // Data receiver parameters
  var files = [],
      bufferArray = [],
      fields = [],
      errors = [],
      form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.uploadDir = process.env.UPLOAD_DIR;
  form.type = true;
  form.keepExtensions = false;

  form.on('field', function(field, value) {
        fields.push([field, value]);
    })
  form.on('file', function(field, file){
    files.push(file);
  });
  form.on('end', function() {
    var jsonData = '';

    // Document processing ...
    files.forEach(function(file){
      let content = fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'binary');
       [...]
     // Once done i've got a nodebuffer of the generated file
        bufferArray.push(doc);
    });
  });

  // Process file receiving
  form.parse(req);

  res.status(200).end();
};
```

Also, i'd like to know if it's possible to manipulate document without saving it, to get rid of this : `fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'binary');`
And stop using disk storage.

I'm pretty new to node.js, all answers welcome (refractoring suggestions too).

Comment: Which version of node are you using?  You will get different answers depending on that.  Newer versions support async/await (v 8.0 +), older versions you'll directly work with promises, or worse, the old fashioned way of dealing with callbacks.

Comment: @dvsoukup I'm currently on node 6.4.11.